# Program isn't giving correct results - case when (SAS)

Tags: sas

```
 /* FLAG_MISMATCH_PAID*/
        (CASE
        WHEN t1.Paid=t2.PAID_AMT THEN "TRUE"
        ELSE "FALSE"
        END) AS FLAG_MISMATCH_PAID
```

This works when I am using other variables, but for some reason I am getting incorrect TRUE/FALSE results when I use this code.  I thought maybe there was some issues with numbers beyond the hundreds unit so I tried using round (x, .01), but correcting for that made no difference.

Why would two numbers that are exactly the same still give me a "FALSE" result? (i.e. t1.Paid = $106,115.23 and t2.PAID_AMT = $106,115.23, and it is flagged as FALSE, yet  t1.Paid =$57,242.11 and t2.PAID_AMT = $57,242.11 is TRUE)

Comment: Please provide sample data and complete code to replicate the issue, or you're not going to get much help here.  Impossible to say from just that snippet.

Comment: Are you sure you have numbers and not characters?

Comment: Sounds like precision/display error. Check that the values have identical precision. 
Comparing fractional values is tricky indeed. I'd suggest that you don't do comparisons with x=y but  x-sigma < y < x+sigma, where sigma is small number. (0.001 should be enough your case) Edit: Sorry fingers are faster than head. of course the comparison is abs(x-y) < sigma

Comment: Yes, it seems like there was a slight rounding issue after all, so using the x-sigma < y < x+sigma solves the issue.  Thanks!